# MonadIO containing resource

Tags: haskell

I'm implementing a bracket-kind pattern.
Say I have some resource. For simplicity, I will use the following

```
data Res = Res Int deriving(Show)

acquire :: IO Res
acquire = do
  print "Acquire:"
  Res . read <$> getLine

release :: Res -> IO ()
release r = do
  print "Result:"
  print r

use :: Res -> IO Res
use r = do
  print r
  let Res x = r in return . Res $ x + 1
```

So I get the behavior of the form

```
main1 :: IO ()
main1 = do
  r <- acquire
  r <- use r
  release r
```

Is it possible to implement `MonadIO` instance called `WithRes`,
that will hold an argument for `use`, so that `use` function will have a simpler form

```
useR :: WithRes ()
useR = ...

acquireR :: WithRes ()
acquireR = ...

releaseR :: WithRes ()
releaseR = ...

runWithRes :: WithRes a -> IO a

main2 :: IO ()
main2 = runWithRes $ do
  acquireR
  useR
  releaseR
```

and in the end I will get `main1 = main2`?

Comment: It looks like you want to use `Res` as a state. So perhaps `type WithRes a = StateT Res IO a`? Though it doesn't apply any restrictions such as you have to call `acquireR` before `useR`, for example.

Comment: @snak, well, I don't. Thing is `Res` is actually a system resource (for example a file). So acquire/release has to be called somewhere. In this example, it has to be called so that `Res` is defined before using.

Comment: Hmm, then, I guess you might want to `acquire` and `release` in `runWithRes` instead of with `acquireR` and `releaseR`, and run the `do` block in `StateT` with the acquired `Res`.

Comment: What would be the advantage of this pattern, compared to regular `bracket`?

Comment: @danidiaz, the advantage is that I have a lot of `use`-like functions (about 100) that take this one state variable, so it is obviously global.

Comment: You can work with a `StateT` monad transformer, but I'm wondering if you can not make something that calls `acquireR` and `releaseR`, so as a "wrapper" that then would have some sort of type like `runWithRes :: (r -> IO ()) -> IO ()`, it thus passes the resource to the "wrapped" function. You can also extend this with a function where you pass the acquire and release function.

Answer (score 0):

As @snak, and @willeM_ Van Onsem mentioned, it appears I actually can use *State monad*. Here is a quick rewrite:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.Bifunctor

newtype WithRes a = WithRes {runWithRes :: Res -> IO (a, Res)}

instance Functor WithRes where
  f `fmap` x = WithRes $ fmap (first f) . runWithRes x

instance Applicative WithRes where
  pure x = WithRes $ return . (x,)
  (<*>) = ap

instance Monad WithRes where
  x >>= f = WithRes $ uncurry runWithRes . first f <=< runWithRes x

instance MonadIO WithRes where
  liftIO x = WithRes $ \r -> (,r) <$> x
```

so `useR` can be written in the following form

```
useR :: WithRes ()
useR = WithRes $ fmap ((),) . use
```

now we can do `acquire` and `release` outside `WithRes` monad to set the initial `Res` value (as snak recommended):

```
main2 :: IO ()
main2 = do
  r <- acquire
  (x, r) <- flip runWithRes r $ do
    useR
    useR
    useR
  release r
```

Or, IMO, we can do even better. We can turn `acquire`/`release` into monadic action

```
acquireR :: WithRes ()
acquireR = WithRes $ \r -> ((),) <$> acquire

releaseR :: WithRes ()
releaseR = WithRes $ \r -> release r >> return ((), Res 0)
```

and add a simple `runWithRes` wrapper called `evalWithRes`, for a better interface

```
evalWithRes :: Res -> WithRes a -> IO a
evalWithRes r w = fst <$> runWithRes w r
```

so we can run the whole process entirely from inside `WithRes` monad

```
main3 :: IO ()
main3 = evalWithRes (Res 0) $ do
  acquireR
  useR
  releaseR
```

Note that we used the default value `Res 0`.
One way to avoid it, is to wrap it into `Maybe`, so if it is `Nothing` the `useR` action must be ignored, but that's another story.

Also, I will notice, that `useR`/`acquireR`/`releaseR` use same pattern of wrap-unwrap the `WithRes` value. To simplify writing such thing, we may add some functions that will work with state, as [transformers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.1.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Strict.html#t:StateT) lib do. But for this problem, there is simply no need.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `bracket` + `ReaderT`. Like this:

```
acquire :: IO Res
release :: Res -> IO ()
useR :: ReaderT Res IO ()
(acquire, release, useR) = undefined

main :: IO ()
main = bracket acquire release (runReaderT useR)
```

You may call `ask` or `asks` inside `useR` to access the resource.